# I'm making my first UI program in Python, and I need help checking the color of a button in an IF statement

Tags: python, button, tkinter, background

I am making my first Python UI program (using tkinter) and I am trying to make a button. When you click this button I want it to turn red, and then when you click it again, have it turn white again. Could I have some help with checking the background color in an `if` statement?

I tried many things such as if `button.background == 'red'`: and  `if button.color == 'red'`: I have also scoured the internet for a while.

This is the code I have so far:

```
    main.title("My Window")
    main.geometry('800x600')

    def colorChange():
      if button == 'red':
            button.configure(background='white')
        else:
            button.configure(background='red')

    button = Button(master, text="Change Color", command=colorChange)
    button.pack()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `cget()` function:

```py
if button.cget('background') == 'red':
    # Code
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would go about it :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.title("My Window")
master.wm_resizable(0, 0)

button_color = 'red'

def colorChange () :
    global button_color
    if button_color == 'red' :
        button_color = 'white'
    else : button_color = 'red'
    button.config (bg = button_color)

button = Button (master, width = 12, bd = 4, bg = button_color,
    font = 'Ariel 12', text = 'Change Color',
    command = lambda : colorChange ())

button.pack ()

mainloop()
```